# Getter/Setter is crashing my code, but is fine in a Function

Tags: c#, performance, get, set, globalization

I want to return a date in the UK format, rather than the US format that it currently stored.

Therefore, I decided to add a getter and setter to the value within my class.

However, when I run the code with a getter and setter in place, the page fails to load.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

// Globalisation for converting dates from American to British format
using System.Globalization;

/// <summary>
/// Class to hold the summary of an order take from database TOEHEAD
/// </summary>
public class OrderSummary
{

    public string order_number { get; set; }
    public string order_date
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                string ukDateTimeFormat = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Parse(this.order_date, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));

                return ukDateTimeFormat;
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                return "Error";
            }
        }

        set
        {
            this.order_date = value;
        }
    }
    public string order_total { get; set; }

    public OrderSummary()
    {

    }

}
```

If I put this code in to a function and return it that way, it works fine.

Have I formatted something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cause a Stack Overflow by calling the same property from your get code

```
string ukDateTimeFormat = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Parse(**this.order_date**, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```

You do this also in the `set`

```
this.**order_date** = value;
```

Fixed code:

```
private string m_order_date;
public string order_date
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            string ukDateTimeFormat = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Parse(m_order_date, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));

            return ukDateTimeFormat;
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            return "Error";
        }
    }

    set
    {
        m_order_date = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Adrian, I didn't add the code tags to see the bold font. That's what important here.

Comment: Thank you, this was baffling me.  I thought that there was a way to do it in the same declaration for the variable.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a circular reference. Your getter for order_date is calling order_date.